# My regular expression works on my pc but not on another one

Tags: c#, regex, windows, windows-server-2016

I've got the following regular expression for smtp server validation:

```
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\w+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{1,3}$");
        return regex.IsMatch("smtp.a-a.com");
```

The string is matched on my Windows 10 pc, but not on pc having Windows Server 2016 OS. The systems have the same culture (IT).

Why is there this different behavior?

Comment: can you please include a code example that actually reproduces the issue?

Comment: Also, FYI, `[a-zA-z0-9-]+` must be written as `[a-zA-Z0-9-]+` if you plan to only match letters, digits and `-`.

Comment: I edited the question adding a code sample